# Why does retrieving a record using Entity Framework take so long?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have written this code for searching a record using a string field.

There are around 33 coulmns to be returned. The code has to pick the matching record from around 1000 records.

The problem is that speed is very slow for this function only.

Comment: Your not using `query`? What is inside `InspectionReportRepository`? Can't you get rid of the `trim` call? Are we talking .net or .net core? What version of entity framework?

Comment: You are obviously using some kind of an extra "layer" (UoW) on top of EF - have you tried is "raw", pure EF is just as slow? So it is *really* EF's fault - or is our UoW layer on top possibly the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: Are you sure `GetQueryable()` returns a LinqToEF queryable or does it return a LinqToObject queryable?